# How are muscle fibre size and oxygen consumption related?

Tags: metabolism, muscles, cellular-respiration

Does anyone know of a paper which correlates the muscle fibre size to oxygen consumption in mammals? I am trying to find a correlation between muscle fibre type, size and (absolute and specific) oxygen consumption.

Comment: How much googling have you done? It seems there was some research: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8904581 http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0026286268900022 Is it relevant?